# Downcut bullnose endmill

Tags: machining, tools

Does anyone know if there exists an endmill that has both a downcut helical geometry and a corner radius (a.k.a. bullnose)? I've seen both qualities in an endmill individually but never together on the same endmill.  I'm trying to understand from a tooling perspective whether this type of endmill is impossible to make or merely not very useful/uncommonly needed.  If so, why?

Comment: I'm not looking for the product, I'm asking why this type of tooling is not supported.  Thanks NMech, but that was my previous question that was taken down because of semantics.

Comment: I was a machinist for two years while in school but have only used my machining knowledge sporadically at subsequent jobs.  I'm a process engineer now and I'm about to test both corner radius endmills and downcut endmills for one of our processes; but I've never even used a corner radius endmill before.  I wanted to find some background info before diving in on the project but there seems to be little to nothing on the combination of downcut and corner radius qualities.  Seems like the type of thing a seasoned machinist unlike myself would have seen as a rarity through the years.

Comment: @Farris Hm, then you should just ask some company like Guhring if they have any and if not why they don't have them.

Comment: If you haven't found it by now, it's obviously quite unusual. My *guess*, considering the purpose of a radius endmill is for pocketing, is that with downcut you'd end up pushing chips down and wedging them into the corner. I know you can get straight-flute radius endmills (ie neither up nor down cut) ... have you considered those for your application?